# Bootstrap: form submit method and jquery plugin not working together

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a `bootstrap` form and button that submits data using `method=post` and a jquery plugin that validates a form with `$('#myform').formValidation`.

Both the button and plugin work separately but when I add them together the validation is working but the form isn't submitting. I am not getting any messages at all.

I suspect the plugin is somehow interfering with the button method in bootstrap but don't know how to address it.

Here is my form:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/addfriend" id="newfriendform">
<div class="container friend">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel panel-heading">
            <div>
                <h3>Add New Friend</h>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="panel panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-2">  
                <label for="firstname">FirstName</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">  
                <label for="middlename">MiddleName</label>
                <input type="text" name="middlename" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Create Friend</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My jquery plugin:

```
   $('#newfriendform').formValidation({
    framework:'bootstrap',
    icon:{
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh',
    },
    fields:{
        firstname:{
            message:"first name is required",
            validators:{
                notEmpty : {
                    message:"Please provide a firstname"
                },
            }
        },
        surname:{
            message:"surname is required",
            validators:{
                notEmpty : {
                    message:"Please provide a surname"
                },
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: prepare a demo if possible

Comment: use button type `submit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you show have button type `submit`

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Friend</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for this. I didn't notice it because it works without type `submit` if I don't use it with a jquery...